# Create EF Provider for a new database provider

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I would like to create a EF provider for a relatively new database provider like DB2. However I am unable to find any useful documentation/tutorials related to it.

There are some articles in ADO.Net blog but the series itself is incomplete.

I would be really thankful if anyone can share useful links to start with it.

Answer (score 0):

Writing an EF provider is certainly a fun challenge especially with the limited information out there.  Your best bet is to start with the [Entity Framework Sample Provider](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFSampleProvider).